# Remove Visual Studio Qt add-in items from project context menu

Tags: visual-studio, qt, contextmenu, add-in

I'm using Qt add-in for Visual studio. It adds some items in project context menu, available from solution explorer. Here is the context menu. Not so small, right? Thanks Qt for additional 8 items, while they are completely duplicated by the main menu and I'm not ever going to use 7 of them anyway.

Is there a way to get rid of them? Uninstalling add-in is not an option.

[image]

Comment: Certainly one solution would be to edit the source code of the plugin to remove those items from the context menu. It should be a trivial change, I'd think.\

Comment: Hmm. So obvious, I didn't think of it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! In Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Customize -> Commands -> Context menu -> Project and Solution Context Menus, and all the items are there! Modify as you want!